# Очередной вопрос верстки Dots для слайдера

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

Не получается сверстать дотсы для слайдера. Использую Slick. Если есть какие-то туториалы создания таких дотсов поделитесь плз. Думаю такое возможно только с использованием SVG. Так как редко использую не имею представления как реализовать такое. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]